# Filter query on calendar events by organizer

Tags: power-automate

Using "Get a calendar view of events (V3)" to retrieve events within a date range. That much is working. When I add a query filter to only get events from a specific organizer, I get an "Invalid filter clause" error.

The filter I've tried is `organizer = 'abc@email.com'` or as shown below it's using the Organizer from the input event.

[image]

The error message:

[image]